Reviewing in the Staging Ground: A practical guide
How should I review questions in the Staging Ground and when should I use which option?
This question is supposed to provide clarifications for reviewers and help with writing reviews.

Is there a reason this is here, as opposed to the help center? or are you proposing updates for the help center (i'd argue the help center covers this topic better currently)

We don't have that information in the help center/I was writing this in addition to what is currently stated in the help center (and focusing on "common antipatterns" I have seen. What I wrote is more focused on practical advice/when exactly the options should be used (maybe similar to What are the guidelines for reviewing?). If the Community agrees with everything I wrote, I can also imagine parts of it being integrated in the help center or it becoming an [tag:faq].

no? literally everything here is just more words saying the same thing as the guidelines but more against publishing questions.

The review guidelines don't have much about using the off-topic option, it doesn't say much about the issues with "Minor Edits" and there are a few other things that often cause some issues which is why I wrote more about that. It's ok that you are disagreeing with it but I think establishing some sort of baseline (we'll see whether people agree) would be useful. Furthermore, this post can be used to be referenced when needed.

We have Meta posts for closing, reviewing, etc. Having one for Staging Ground seems normal/helpful.

It's pretty much the Theme of Stack Overflow (TM) that Help Center articles are accurate enough but don't really give actionable advice, and then all the regulars have inferred the actionable advice (from some combination of experience, common sense, general cluefulness about the site's telos, and argument on Meta) and blithely assume they didn't do anything special to get there. Besides, Meta Q&A is actually under the community's control, and can be used as a duplicate target when someone asks a question that should have been answered by the Help Center.

Should this be [[meta-tag:faq-proposed]]?

@Bergi I wanted to see whether people agree with the overall content first (see my comment above) but this seems to be the case given the votes on this post so I added that tag now.

@KarlKnechtel except the edit page. The edit page categorically says that edit if you can make the post better. Also, go away if you don't want people editing your posts. Meta gaslight itself into thinking that that means something else however.

Overview
The goal of the Staging Ground is to improve the overall quality of new questions on the main site, by providing a place to fix those questions before publishing them on the main site.
The Staging Ground is a place where you can, and should, try to work together with askers to improve their questions. It empowers you to triage questions, offer detailed feedback on issues with the question while not cluttering the main site; it avoids discouraging the OP with the stigma of a "closed" banner on a fixable question. (In principle, a closed question on the main site is supposed to be edited by the OP and nominated for reopening. But not all questions can be fixed, and in practice, users often perceive question closure as a rejection and don't edit the question.)
When you read a question in the Staging Ground, your first task is triage. New questions basically fall into the following categories:

Can't be fixed to accept new answers (either a duplicate or off-topic; would be closed on the main site without an expectation of being re-opened). Currently there is no special facility to publish duplicate questions and then close them as duplicates, even if they would be good signposts.

Can be fixed, requiring information or edits that only the OP can provide. This roughly corresponds to "Needs details or clarity", "Not written in English", "Needs more focus" and "Needs debugging details" closure reasons. (When a question is not written in English, of course, it's not necessarily known whether OP can translate it, nor whether the translated version would be on topic.)

Can be fixed by someone else - it just has the wrong tags, or should be edited to remove noise, or something else along those lines.

Meets all standards and can be published as-is.


Require Major Changes is your main tool
Most important changes need to be done by the asker.
If there is any improvement to be made to a question by the asker, write a comment saying what is missing or should be changed and use the "Requires Major Changes" option. This option should be used if there are any changes the author should make before their question can be published.
You can use a comment template and possibly change it to fit your needs if that helps.
Using the "Requires Major Changes" option tells the author that they need to edit their question and add these details in order for their question to be published and answered, makes sure it isn't published automatically, and marks it as reviewed (until the author submits it for Re-Evaluation).
If you are writing a comment asking the author to change something, consider using this option.
Don't overuse "Vote as off-topic"
Only use the "Vote as off-topic" option if you think the question cannot be changed to be on-topic without fundamentally changing what the question is about. This includes questions that are not about programming (e.g. if the question should be asked on a different Stack Exchange site) or opinion-based questions. When using this option, make sure the asker understands why their question is off-topic. If the close-reason doesn't tell them in an obvious way, please write a comment explaining why the question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. For example, if the question is about general computing, hardware or software and not about programming, you can write a comment telling them about Super User.
Don't use this option for "bad questions". Instead, tell the asker what problems their question has/what they have to change and use "Requires Major Changes".
For example, if a question "lacks focus", asks multiple questions in one post, or is missing an MRE (or proper specification for a how-to question), you should use "Requires Major Changes" instead.
Look for duplicates if you can
If you might be able to identify a duplicate in the Staging Ground, please look for one and mark the question as such. A question being correctly marked as a duplicate and the author's problem being solved by that is an ideal outcome. If you think the author may need additional information to understand why their question is a duplicate (for example the question isn't exactly the same but the answers solve their problem or they should consider multiple answers of the linked question), you can write an additional comment explaining that.
If a question is a duplicate of a combination of other questions, you can mark it as a duplicate of one of these questions and write a comment linking to the other questions.
If the author asked the same question multiple times, you can mark their question as a duplicate of their other question and tell them they shouldn't ask the same question multiple times if applicable.
Use "Minor Edits" sparingly
The "Conditionally approve pending minor edits" option allows the author to publish the question as soon as they make an edit to their question (or it is automatically published if the author doesn't edit it within 24h), no matter how meaningless that edit is. Only use this option if you think the question is ok to be published as-is but there is something where the author could still improve it.
If the author needs to make a change (even if it is just a small change) before the question can be published, use the "Requires Major Changes" option instead.
Edit improvements (formatting, spelling, title, tags, ...)
If you can improve anything about the question by yourself (e.g. the title, tags, spelling, grammar/wording, clarity, etc) without changing the meaning of that question, just edit it. You can still submit your review or skip the question after submitting your edit. If you want to make an edit without submitting a review (or submitting a review after the edit), you can use the "Save without review" option.
Don't answer in the Staging Ground
Don't answer questions in the Staging Ground.
If you can find a duplicate target, vote to mark the question as a duplicate (if you immediately know the answer by looking at the question, that's an indicator that it has probably been asked before).
If you think you might know the answer but the question doesn't have sufficient information to be properly answerable (e.g. it would just be a guess), ask the author to provide the necessary clarifications.
If the question properly provides all details necessary and has no other issues, you can approve it (you can make a polishing edit, e.g. improving the title and tags if applicable) and write an answer.
When to approve questions
If a question satisfies all the following requirements, you can approve it:

It's on-topic and actually asks a question.
It contains all necessary information (including a MCVE if necessary).
It's clear/focused on what exactly it's asking about.
It seems to be answerable by subject-matter experts (SME).
None of Stack Overflow's close reasons apply as far as you can judge (without necessarily being a SME).
You aren't reasonably able to identify a duplicate.
The title summarizes the question and it's properly tagged.

If applicable, you might want to polish the question (e.g. improve the title/tags, remove clutter, etc) by editing before approving the question.
Questions don't need to be perfect to be approved and published to the main site. Just improve them as best as you can and if you think it's a good Stack Overflow question, you can approve it. Don't worry about some of the questions you approved being closed. If subject-matter experts knowing more than you about the topic decide the question is still off-topic, that's fine. You cannot prevent all closures but you can improve questions and increase the chance of questions staying open as good as you can.
Questions/discussion/needing help reviewing
If you want to discuss reviewing in the Staging Ground or need help with it, you can join the Staging Ground Discussion/Support chatroom or create a post on Meta Stack Overflow if applicable. Of course, if you don't know what to do with some question, you can always skip it.

This is inspired by the answers of the Staging Ground Beta team post What should be the target quality level for posts to be approved? Should all posts ideally require an SME to review? (requires access) and the Staging Ground Reviewer guidelines.

I'm still wary of promoting a clear, non-duplicate question that is utterly trivial. There's definitely a place on SO for simple answers to simple questions, but there are still some questions that cannot be prettied up enough to have a long or even short-but-happy life on the main site.

The reviewer can't generally know whether such a question is "utterly trivial" or not and they especially can't predict how useful a question will be. While I agree there are question where reviewers would suspect these questions not doing well, it's not something reviewers would know. IMO these questions are still best handled on the main site. However, reviewers might be able to identify a duplicate for many trivial questions (and there's also the "typo"/"nonreproducible" close reason that can apply in some cases but I kinda avoided mentioning that as I don't want it to be overused).

It's well established that "it's in the documentation" isn't a reason to close a question, unless perhaps it's motivated by a misreading of documentation (mental typo). The questions people want to dismiss as "trivial" are often quite the opposite - unfocused, but seen as boring because they're essentially homework. We close those because they're unfocused: we don't do general problem-solving for the OP (breaking a problem down into logical steps). But either way, I don't think this meta Q&A is the right place for guidance about closure reasons; that's covered elsewhere.

On the other hand, when I'm reviewing stuff in my wheelhouse, and I don't review anything that isn't, I've got a pretty good feel for how a question will be received by those active in my wheelhouse. I'm not going to promote a question that'll be crushed by downvotes and closed within minutes of hitting the main page. This is an advantage of knowing what I'm reviewing, even if that means I don't get to review much. The downside to my view is some of those questions do deserve an answer, but it sometimes requires herculean effort on the part of some users to reopen the question and keep it open

What I've found works is to write the answer before promoting it. I've found I can reliably get the answer up before the question's closed. I can take a few downvotes, and if I'm right, eventually I'll break even off the other noobs with the same question.

Side note: I'm right with you on the nuke-by-typo. A simple misunderstanding of the documentation or a language rule is not a typo. Swapping i with j, that's a typo. Most of the time.

With the Staging Ground (a) you aren't expected to be a subject-matter expert when reviewing a question (though it can certainly be helpful, especially for identifying duplicates) and (b) doing this is still possible in the Staging Ground. You can improve the question as good as you can (together with the author) and nothing stops you from answering the question after publishing.

I'm wary of the phrase "it contains all necessary information". see #1 and #2 of https://stackoverflow.com/help/staging-ground-reviewer-guidelines. "You don’t have to be a subject matter expert on the question in order to review it. If it looks like it [...]" and "appears to have all the information necessary to answer the question". I also feel like this answer should start with a prominent callout to that help center page.

@dan1st Could you mention what happens to a Qt with 'Minor Edits' if the Asker doesn't do any Edit at all, does it remain "for ever" like that, or will it get anyway automatically published after 24h...? (And if 24h, is it 24h after the Creation Timestamp, or 24h after the last Comment...?) I'm very-very reluctant to use that Option (now) as "I think" I saw 1 or 2 Qt's I had put in 'Minor Edits' and still got (automatically?) published while the Asker didn't react anymore... // There is no "s" at "Require[s]" in 'Require Major changes" in the 'SG'...  + no "pending" in 'Minor Edits'...

@chivracq Good catch. Yes, if the author doesn't edit the question, it will be automatically published (I added it to the answer). The option is mainly for question that are ok as-is but whether that option is really necessary is a different discussion.

if you think it's a good Stack Overflow question, - IMO, "good" is a much higher bar than "valid" / "I wouldn't vote to close in this state on the main site" which is what we should be using as a criterion for approving from the staging ground.  In my book, a "good" question is one deserving an upvote, and those are much rarer.

There are also questions I don't think are interesting or useful which I might even downvote, but don't fit any of the close reasons. I'm less sure about approving those from the SG.  When those appear on main, I sometimes try to help the OP in comments if I think that's possible in a comment or two, even if I don't think the question has future value even if it is mostly answerable.  IDK how to handle that on SG.

If you are unsure, you can always skip questions. If there's anything you think can be approved or if there are any issues with the question, you can use "Requires Major Changes". For other questions (that also fit the criteria mentioned for approving), you can probably approve them.

Yes, I've also seen a few posts I marked with "minor edits" that later got auto-published without any update from the OP. Because of this I'll never use that option unless the post can truly already stand on its own without the suggested minor edit. It's a shame it doesn't at least require an edit by the OP prior to being published. I know a lot of thought and testing went into SG but this seems like a gap in functionality IMO.

"The goal of the Staging Ground is to improve questions before they are posted on the main site" - yeah I would hope it would also be to get understanding into the heads of people sooner that Stack Overflow is not a get out of jail free card to dumping problems on other people and then going out for pizza, but I probably expect too much.

@Gimby I don't know how to formulate that in a nice way.

@Gimby people are going to do that in SG anyway and it's much better that it's contained there rather than leaking onto the main site. If the ensuing feedback helps people walk away with a better impression (or at least a better understanding) of the site, so much the better.

A copy-paste comment for something I'm sick of retyping with minor variations: Please make sure to **select "Require Major changes" status** for questions where OP must change something in order to have a question that meets the site's standards. Questions marked "Conditionally approve with Minor edits", or not marked, may be published automatically even if the OP doesn't change anything. The goal here is to avoid questions being downvoted and closed after they're published. See the [practical guide to SG reviews on the Meta site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431934) for details.
